# Minimum processor speed for 16.04

Tags: system-requirements

I have an Intel Pentium N3700 at 1.6 Ghz. Am I out of luck with 16.04?  If so, what is then suitable? Please and thanks in advance.

Comment: please add more information about your system! - amount of RAM memory? graphic card? ...?

Comment: try Ubuntu MATE

Answer (score 0):

I run multiple computers with processors slower than the Pentium N3700.  I haven't noticed much difference in processing power with 16.04 over earlier releases, but I haven't done any benchmarks. I have found, however, that some video cards have performance issues.

I say see what the performance is like on your hardware running a trial from the installation media.  If the applications perform to your liking (or not), then you have your answer.

Comment: thanks for all answers.  I got it going so I was lazy about answering.  Sorry about the duplicate.  I suppose it is just as well as with Win10, but then it seems awkward when it loads.   I just did have a system freeze that required a hard shutdown.